# Как программно скрыть view из другой activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня есть 2 `activity`: `MainActivity` и `SecondActivity`.

Как, нажав на `CheckBox` из второй `активити`, скрыть кнопку, находящуюся на первой? Нужно, что бы она исчезала и появлялась в зависимости от состояния `CheckBox`.

Comment: может стоит посмотреть в сторону хранения значения состояния `CheckBox` в `Preferences` и в `MainActivity` принимать решение об отображении кнопки в зависимости от установленного в `Preferences` значения? Ну и собственно в `SecondActivity` устанавливать это значение в `Preferences`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать какую-нибудь переменную, например булевую, во второй активности, и, в зависимости от состояния checkbox возвращать значение булевой переменной в первую активность, в первой активности при принятии результата можно устанавливать видимость кнопки. [Подробнее здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html).
Примерно как-то так:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (data == null) {return;}
 boolean check = data.getBooleanExtra("check");
 if(check){
    mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}else{
    mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в момент возвращения на первую `activity` передать значение из чекбокса. А в первой получить и скрыть кнопку.
[Получение результата операции](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)